# Product Topology generated by $\mathbf{d}$ coincides with $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}_1\times \mathcal{T}_2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a lemma in my textbook where I don't understand some parts of the proof. Here's the lemma:

If $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ are two metric spaces and $\mathcal{T_1}$ and $\mathcal{T_2}$ the corresponding topologies on $X_2$ and $X_2$, then for any choice of $p$ with $1\leq p \leq \infty$ the topology induced by the metric $\mathbf{d}$ on $X \times Y$ defined as:

> If $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are two metric spaces then for any $p\in [1,\infty]$
> $$\mathbf{d}_p((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)):=(d_X(x_1,y_1)^p+d_Y(x_2,y_2)^p)^{1/p}$$
> for $p\in [1,\infty)$
> And $\text{max}(d_X(x_1,y_1),d_Y(x_2,y_2))$ for $p=\infty$

coincides with the product topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X_1 \times X_2$ defined as

> Suppose the $(T_1,\mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(T_2,\mathcal{T}_2)$ are two topological spaces. Then the producct toplogy on $T_1\times T_2$ is the toplogy $\mathcal{T}$ with basis $$\mathcal{B}=\{U_1\times U_2 : U_1\in \mathcal{T}_1, U_2\in\mathcal{T}_2\}$$

The proof for this is the following:

For simplicity of notation we prove the result for the case $$\mathbf{d}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=d_1(x_1,x_2)+d_2(y_1,y_2)$$

i.e we take $p=1$. But the argument for other values of $p$ is almost identical (All the $\mathbf{d}_p$ metric are topologically equivalent).

Suppose $V\in \mathcal{T}$; we want to show that $V$ is open when we use the $\mathbf{d}$-metric on $X_1\times X_2$.

Since $V\in \mathcal{T}$ we have $V=\cup_i U_1^i\times U_2^i$, with $U^i_j\in\mathcal{T}_j$. So given any $(x,y)\in V, (x,y) \in U_1^j\times U_2^j$ for some $j$: there exists $\epsilon_1$ such that $B_{d_1}(x,\epsilon_1)\subset U^j_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that $B_{d_2}(y,\epsilon)\subset U^j_2$. It follows that $$B_{\mathbf{d}}((x,y),\text{min}(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2))\subset U_1^j\times U^j_2\subset V$$ so $V$ is open in the $\mathbf{d}$-metric

> In this part of the proof, I don't particularly understand why is "So given any $(x,y)\in V, (x,y) \in U_1^j\times U_2^j$ for some $j$: there exists $\epsilon_1$ such that $B_{d_1}(x,\epsilon_1)\subset U^j_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that $B_{d_2}(y,\epsilon)\subset U^j_2$" true? My confusion is that the sets $U_i^j$ are not defined to have been induced by the $d_i$ metrics. Or have they? Maybe i'm not understanding something from the lemma which states otherwise.

(Proof continuation) Now we show that if $U\in X_1\times X_2$ is open in the $mathbf{d}$-metric it an element of $\mathcal{T}$, by showing that $U$ can be written as $$U=\bigcup_{(x,y)\in U}B_X(x,\epsilon(x,y))\times B_Y(y,\epsilon(x,y))$$

for some $\epsilon(x,y)>0$. This is sufficient, as all $d_i$-open balls are contained in $\mathcal{T}_i$.

> Here I don't understand exactly why by showing that $U$ is a union of the balls, then it's an element of $\mathcal{T}_i$? Is this because since $U$ is open then the balls from $X$ and $Y$ are open, and hence the balls  form a basis for $\mathcal{T}_X$ or $\mathcal{T}_Y$ and hence by showing that if $U$ is a union of the products of these open sets (balls), then it's generated by the sets from the base and hence it's an element of $\mathcal{T}$?

(Proof continuation) Given any $(x,y)\in U$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_{\mathbf{d}}((x,y),\epsilon)\subset U$. By the definition of $\mathbf{d}$, we have (1)

$$B_{d_1}(x,\epsilon/2)\times B_{d_2}(y,\epsilon/2)\subset B_{\mathbf{d}}((x,y),\epsilon)\subset U$$

taking the union over all $(x,y)\in U$ now yields (1)

> Here I don't understand why from the definition of $\mathbf{d}$:
> $$B_{d_1}(x,\epsilon/2)\times B_{d_2}(y,\epsilon/2)\subset B_{\mathbf{d}}((x,y),\epsilon)$$ In particular where did they come up with the $\epsilon/2$'s with?

Comment: For 1., this is by the definition of the topology induced by a metric. For 2., your understanding is correct (though the balls being open has nothing to do with $U$ being open. they are open by definition of the respective metric topologies, hence the product of balls are parts of the basis of the product topology and a union over elements of the base is open in the topology by definition). For 3., have you tried checking this directly?

Comment: @Thorgott i'm not sure what to do to check it directly

Comment: Take a point $(x^{\prime},y^{\prime})\in B_{d_1}(x,\epsilon/2)\times B_{d_2}(y,\epsilon/2)$ and estimate $d((x,y),(x^{\prime},y^{\prime}))$. There is no difficulty once you spell out what the first containment actually means.